# References for examples of flat and non flat morphisms with solutions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness

I am looking for exercises/examples of "simple enough" morphisms between varieties being flat/non-flat, with solutions. I have only ever found a handful of examples, however very rarely with solutions to check my work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Here are some examples already on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178121/intuition-for-%c3%a9tale-morphisms/178163#178163). [Here are some more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666113/examples-of-morphisms-of-schemes-to-keep-in-mind/666486#666486).